# Microsoft Excel 2016 64-bit memory issue with form control

Tags: 64-bit

I was having difficulties operating a workbook in Excel 2016 64-bit that was originally built using Excel 2010 32-bit.  The workbook has several form control combo boxes.  The moment you click on the drop down, excel freezes for a second or two and then stops responding.  Then, I get the message: 
"There isn't enough memory to complete this action. Tru using less data or closing other applications.  To increase memory availability, consider: -Using a 64-bit version of Microsoft Excel. -Adding memory to your device."

Sooo... I opened a fresh workbook in excel 2016. Created a form control combo box.  I set up the Input range:, Cell link:, and Drop down lines: in the Control tab of the Format control menu.  I then saved and closed the workbook, reopened the workbook, and then tried selecting something from the drop down.  I got the same memory issue message that I was getting before.

It's not just happening on my computer.  My colleagues are seeing the same thing on their 64-bit machines as well.  Anyone else have issues with form controls in excel 2016 64-bit version, specifically the combo box??

Comment: Just to follow up with my question: If I open up said workbook and do any sort of action prior to clicking on the drop-box, it works.  For example, if I change the value of any random cell in the workbook, then the drop-box works as intended.  It makes no sense!

Comment: Better ask this on the [Microsoft Community](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us).